# Get value from sorting data in Kolin

Tags: sorting, kotlin

My task is to return ArrayList of type transactionsList

First I have to parse date in string and then stream it (ascending)

I know how to do that but sortedWith give back type Unit not Array.

```
 val cmp = compareBy<transactionsList> { LocalDate.parse(it.date, 
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy.")) }


        val sortedList: List<transactionsList> = ArrayList()

      acountTransactionList
          . sortedWith(cmp)
          .forEach(::println)

        return acountTransactionList
```

I cannot store data from that sort because it gives me type Unit.

Comment: It seems like something is messed up here. `sortedWith()` returns list, not `Unit`. How is `acountTransactionList` defined? How do you check `sortedWith()` returns `Unit`? Actually, `forEach()` returns `Unit` if this is what you mean.

Comment: List: acountTransactionList: ArrayList<transactionsList>

Comment: Yes, but how to store that into sortedList

Comment: Just assign the result of `sortedWith(cmp)` to `sortedList` (instead of `ArrayList()`).

Comment: If I do that, It gives me an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works as intended (the issue is that `forEach()` method returns `Unit`, not each object):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val acountTransactionList: ArrayList<transactionsList> = arrayListOf(transactionsList("10.10.2010."),
        transactionsList("10.10.2000."),
        transactionsList("10.09.2010."),
        transactionsList("10.11.2010."),
        transactionsList("11.11.2010."),
        transactionsList("10.10.2001."))

    val cmp = compareBy<transactionsList> {
        LocalDate.parse(it.date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy."))
    }

    val sortedList: List<transactionsList> = acountTransactionList.sortedWith(cmp)
    println(sortedList)
}

data class transactionsList(val date: String)
```

Comment: I rearranged ArrayList to List, and it works !